# how to extract labels sequentially using ConnectedComponents?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, connected-components

This is my input image:

[image]

I want to extract each object in the image according to the labeling by 
`ConnectedComponents`, but `ConnectedComponents` doesn't label each object in sequence.

So when I extract each label I get a sequence like this:

[image]

Are there other ways to extract labels sequentially using `ConnectedComponents`?

This is my code:

```
image = cv2.imread("/Users/server/Documents/Data Teks/Ayah/T11_F1_D5.jpg")

plt.subplot(241)
plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.title('Image')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
t, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 105, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

connectivity = 8 
num_labels, label= cv2.connectedComponents(thresh, connectivity)
label = label + 1

thresh = cv2.cvtColor(thresh,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

h, w = thresh.shape[:2]
for index in range(1, num_labels):
    mask = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)
    mask[label == index + 1] = 1
    obj = thresh * mask[:, :, np.newaxis]
    obj = obj[..., : : -1]

    plt.subplot(1, 7, index)
    plt.imshow(obj)
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.title(index)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Of course the labels are in sequence. It's just that the components are labeled in *vertical* sequence and that is apparently not what you want. You have at least a couple of options: transpose the image before labeling, or sort the components horizontally after labeling.

Comment: Actually, transposing the image might not even get them in the order you desire. You'd have to try it out.

Comment: @beaker I tried to transpose the image before labeling and it worked. Thank you